# android.util.Pair<F, S> example in Android

Tags: java, android, generics

I want to return a tuple of `double` data types. I am unable to create `Pair`. I have read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair.html)  but unable to make it.
I am doing as

```
private Pair myNums(double F, double S) {
        Pair<F f, S s> p = Pair.create(F, S);
        return p;
    }
```

But it is saying

> Unknown class F

Comment: Checkout this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/40259531/2705391

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F and S are the type. In your case is `Double`.

```
Pair<Double, Double> p = Pair.create(F, S);
```

Comment: and for the retreival of doubles?

Comment: what do you mean? you should return `Pair<Double, Double>`

Comment: How can I retrieve these doubles? Something like this `double F  = mynums(), double second = mynums()`.....

Comment: no. You are returning a Pair, so you should assign it to a Pair object. `Pair<Double, Double> x = mynums();`. You should learn java btw

Comment: How to open the pair? How to save both nums in different `double` variables where the function calls?

Comment: check the documentation of Pair. You will find that you can access two different properties, called `first` and `second`. E.g. `Pair<Double, Double> x = mynums(); doubla a = x.first;`

Answer (score 1):

Try `private <T, S> Pair<T, S> myNums(...) {}`. in Java, you must specify the generics before the return type of the method. But you cannot specify `double` as your argument types. Ideally, do not specify types in your arguments as this will make your method truly generic.

E.g

```
private <T, S> Pair<T, S> myNums(T t, S s) {
    // do work to create the Pair and return
}
```

Just remember, if you're using generics, then use the power of generics in Java, don't then specify types like double, int or String. It really defeats the very essence and reason why generics are used and their intention.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
private Pair myNums() {
    Pair<String, Integer> p = Pair.create("Prashant M", 1000);
    return p;
}
```